# NodeJS: Integrate with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, express, socket.io

I've heared that NodeJS is great for making real-time chat applications and I want to implement a chat on my website. Right now I only have the design so I have to make the back-end code now.

However when I'm using `socket.io + express` it doesn't work out like it should.

Code from `server.js`:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.php');
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

I simply want to show `index.php` on `localhost:3000`, however when I browse to the website it doesn't want to show the page. Instead it downloads the `index.php` file.

But if I change the extention of the file to html, so it becomes `index.html`, it works. But that is not what I want.

I know there are some smart guys out there that can solve this problem in no time. I've been sitting for a very long time myself trying to sovle it.

[image: The website]

Comment: At [so] you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Comment: I've posted this to learn, not for someone to make it for me.

Comment: Unfortunately that is not allowed here. This isn't a tutorial site, google, or the manual. It's for developers who have written some code and need help understanding why it isn't working as expected.

Comment: Yes, and in this case i need help understanding why it downloads the file instead of showing it. That way I can know how to proceed with the project myself.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `php-express` package to render PHP files with Express:

```
npm install --save php-express
```

Then use this *(make sure you have PHP installed on your machine)*:

server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var phpExpress = require('php-express')({
  binPath: 'php'
});

// set view engine to php-express
app.set('views', './views');
app.engine('php', phpExpress.engine);
app.set('view engine', 'php');

// routing all .php file to php-express
app.all(/.+\.php$/, phpExpress.router);

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

*Source:* https://www.npmjs.com/package/php-express