# wired error about sending a post request via ajax

Tags: javascript, php, node.js

I want to make a post request to php file via ajax like this:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/app/preload.php',
        data: {id: "testdata", directories: directories},
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: function(result) {
            if(preloadFirstTime === false) return; 
            console.log('result:', result);
            preload(result);
            preloadFirstTime = false;
        },
    });
```

But I get this error:

[image]

The wired thing is I can download the PHP file with the address I get the error:

I mean this addres:

> https://localhost:4000/app/preload.php

[image]

Any clue what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

I think I found out why this happens I used this in my node.js server:

```
app.use('/app', express.static(__dirname + '/views/app/files'));
```

I think this handles the get requests but ajax is sending post request !!!!

Comment: You haven't provided a [mcve]. If a GET request and a POST request give different results then either something is different about how the server handles those different requests or you made a typo somewhere.

Comment: Why have you tagged this [tag:node.js] and [tag:php] but not included any Node.js or PHP code in the question? Those are two technologies that are almost never used in conjunction anyway (unless Node.js is being used as a build tool for client-side code which would make it largely irrelevant here).

Comment: There is another difference between those calls. The Ajax request calls localhost using `https` while the screen dump of the brower seem to be using `http`

Comment: No... Using https I can download the file too...

Comment: How are you serving your PHP files? A web server? Or are you trying to run PHP through node.js? If you're trying to server them through node.js, it won't work. Node can't parse PHP. If you're using a web server, then you need to install PHP support. The file shouldn't be downloaded.

Comment: Please have a look at my Edit...

Comment: I'm using https server on my computer (localhost development). the php file is inside the `views/app/files` folder ... I just want to request a post to the php file and I know it works if I could properly send the post req (the php worked last time)

Answer (score 0):

The `static` middleware is designed to serve static files.

Static files do not process data. It makes no sense to make a POST request to a static file.

(That you get a 404 error and not a 405 could be considered a bug in the module).

---

PHP is not JavaScript. While there are modules that will execute PHP via Node.js that you could investigate (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44354530/nodejs-integrate-with-php/44354600)), I wouldn't recommend it.

Either:

- Change to an HTTP server that supports PHP *or*
- Rewrite the PHP in JavaScript and register it with `app.post()` or `router.post()`.

---

Aside. The `views` directory is traditionally reserved for templates that will be used with [a template engine](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html). It will be confusing to anyone trying to maintain your code to find a directory with that name designated for static files.

Comment: Static files do not process data. So if I move my PHP file out of the static folder it should work right?

Comment: Please note that I call The Ajax request from client side...

Comment: @SaraRee — No. If you just move them out of the static folder then you will not being using the code which serves them as static files and, instead, you will have no code that serves them at all.

Comment: Your answer doesn't make sense this used to work before (somehow!)

Comment: Your claim is completely at odds with how the modules your Node.js code is using. It should not ever have worked.

Comment: So you say we can not ever send a post request to a php file via node?!

Comment: No. I said it was a bad idea (see paragraph #4) and that your approach won't work (see paragraphs #1 and #2).